# Start YouTube activity for result

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I'd like to implement a feature in my app that would allow a user to add YouTube videos to his profile. The thing is that I don't really like the approach to add a URL manually. Instead I think it would be much simpler to open YouTube app on a channel of the user and let him select a video. After this I want a link transferred to the app so that I can process it and send a video.

Is there a way to do that with a general `startActivityForResult()` or the YouTube API? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`YouTubeStandalonePlayer`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeStandalonePlayer) class that creates intents that will play Youtube videos in a standalone player activity. This class is a very easy way to play YouTube videos within your application.

> ```
> Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(context, YOUR_DEVELOPER_KEY, VIDEO_ID);
>  startActivity(intent);
> ```

Here is the method you can use under `YoutubeStandalonePlayer` Class:

> *static* **YouTubeInitializationResult**
>
> *getReturnedInitializationResult*(Intent data)
>
> If you start the `YouTubeStandalonePlayer` activity with `startActivityForResult`, you can
>   use this method to transform the data intent passed back in
>   `onActivityResult` into a `YouTubeInitializationResult`.

Comment: thank you for the useful information. This doesn't answer my question. Quote from the docs: `Returns: A YouTubeInitializationResult which is either SUCCESS if the standalone player started successfully, or provides details of the error which prevented the standalone player from starting.`How is that relevant to the video URL?